# Number of positive integer solutions of the equation $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=n$

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions has the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=n
$$
where $x_i>0$ for all $i=\overline{1,k}$ ?

I think that it has $n-1 \choose k-1$ different solutions. Am I right?

I know that the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=n
$$
where $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i=\overline{1,k}$ has $n+k-1 \choose n$ different solutions.

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: See also [this Stars and Bars article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).

Comment: See also [this other Stars and Bars article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).